# Is $Max${$F(X),G(Y)$} necessarily a distribution function

Tags: probability

If $F(X)$ and $G(Y)$ denote two cumulative distribution functions, i.e. $$F(x)=P(X \le x)$$ & $$G(y) = P(Y \le y)$$ then is $Max${$F(X),G(Y)$} necessarily a cumulative distribution function as well?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail in your question please?

Comment: @sos440, Yes, I am referring to the same. Can you illustrate please?

Comment: Any function $H$ that is non-decreasing, right-continuous and satisfies $\lim_{x\to-\infty} H(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} H(x) = 1$ is the CDF of *some* random variable. Just check that your function satisfies these properties.

Answer (score 2):

A function $F : \Bbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ is a CDF if and only if

1. $F$ is right-continuous,
2. $F$ is monotone increasing,
3. $\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 1$.

Now we check that these properties are preserved by $\max$.

1. Let $F$ and $G$ satisfy this property. Then by the continuity of $(x, y) \mapsto \max \{x, y\}$, it follows that
   $$\lim_{y \downarrow x} \max\{F(y), G(y)\}
   = \max\{\lim_{y \downarrow x} F(y), \lim_{y \downarrow x} G(y)\}
   = \max\{F(x), G(x)\}. $$
   So the right-continuity is preserved by $\max$.
2. Suppose $x \leq y$. Then $F(x) \leq F(y)$ and $G(x) \leq G(y)$. This gives $F(x), G(x) \leq \max \{ F(y), G(y) \}$ and hence we have $\max\{F(x), G(x)\} \leq \max\{F(y), G(y)\}$.
3. This again follows from the continuity of $(x, y) \mapsto \max \{x, y\}$. Just check it by yourself!